# How to make a text disappear after certain amount of time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pygame, tk-toolkit

I am really new to Python. I have a memory game assignment. I've started doing it but I am kind of stuck right now because I have to generate numbers that are gonna appear on the screen and disappear after 2 seconds.  I managed to generate the numbers and I put the numbers as text on a label but can't make them disappear. Is there a function to do it?

Comment: Hi @Birkan, it's a good practice to include your code (or a link) along with your question.

Comment: Still, I can give a vague suggestion - create a new thread, and make it overwrite the text to hide by "" (empty string), periodically after whatever time you want. That's as far as I can think without seeing the code.

Comment: @roshnet: threads add way too much overhead for such a simple task.

Comment: @BryanOakley I totally agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `Tkinter` there are some options for "forgetting" (making the label disappear).

```
label.pack_forget()
```

```
label.place_forget()
```

If you used pack then use `pack_forget()` and if your using place use `place_forget()`. To make them reappear, use the `pack` or `place` function again. To wait a certain amount of time you can use `time.sleep` but the better option is to use `.after()`

```
tk.after(10, function)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.I was able to do it easily using the after method

Comment: @Birkan if this fixed you problem if you can make it as the answer that would be great!